# What triplestore that can handle the largest number of triples?

Tags: linked-data, rdf, sparql

A [triplestore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore) is a special database engine containing information triples and answering to SPARQL requests.

What is currently the triplestore that can contain most triples, while still being able to process basic SPARQL queries correctly?

The number of triples needs to have been demonstrated/documented.

Comment: As a starting point, there's a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921407/triplestore-for-large-datasets) over at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The W3C hosts a [list of large triple stores](http://www.w3.org/wiki/LargeTripleStores) with documented deployments and numbers of triples.

The top contenders with more than 10B triples currently are:

- [AllegroGraph](http://franz.com/agraph/allegrograph/) (1Trillion+)
- [Stardog](http://stardog.com/) (50B)
- [Oracle Spatial and Graph](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/options/spatial/) with Oracle Database (48B+)
- [OpenLink Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) v6.1 (15.4B+)
- [Ontotext GraphDB (formerly BigOWLIM)](http://www.ontotext.com/products/ontotext-graphdb/) (12B+)
- [Garlik 4store](http://4store.org/) (15B)
- [Bigdata](http://www.bigdata.com/bigdata) (12.7B)